# t-sql convert datetimeoffset with utc+01:00 to local amsterdam datetime

Tags: t-sql, datetime, datetimeoffset

I want to run a simple T-SQL SELECT query such that this input (datetimeoffset)...

2015-01-01 00:15:00.0000000 +01:00

OR

2015-05-04 14:15:00.0000000 +02:00

...comes out as this output (datetime):

2015-01-01 01:15:00

OR

2015-05-04 16:15:00

Input is one column and output should also be one column.

Any ideas?

UPDATE 20170126

Ok as always it is never as easy as I think. The query is part of a bigger query, which I have now formulated as follows (see below), the input column being named 'TimeStamp' and the output column being named 'Tijd'. This doesn't work though as it doesn't seem to recognize [TimeStamp] in the declaration of the variable. What am I missing?

```
DECLARE @dt datetimeoffset = (SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset, [TimeStamp]))
SELECT @dt as Original
      ,CONVERT(datetime2,@dt,1) AS Tijd
      ,[Id]
      ,[EanCode]
      ,[DataAccessPointId]
      ,[DataSource]
      ,[ElectricityUsageNormalkWh] AS Piek
      ,[ElectricityUsageLowkWh] AS Dal
      ,[DateAltKey] = CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varchar(8), [TimeStamp], 112))
      ,[TimeAltKey] = DATEPART(hh,[TimeStamp]) * 10000 + DATEPART(mi,[TimeStamp]) * 100 + DATEPART(ss,[TimeStamp])
  FROM [dbo].[ElectricityTelemetryData]
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you have your time offset logic the wrong way around in your question regarding your +/- values, but you have a couple options depending on the data type you want as output:

```
declare @dt datetimeoffset = (select convert(datetimeoffset,'2015-01-01 00:15:00.0000000 +01:00'))

select @dt as Original
      ,convert(datetime2,@dt,1) as Converted
      ,switchoffset(@dt,'+00:00') as Switched
```

Output:

```
Original                            | Converted                     | Switched
2015-01-01 00:15:00.0000000 +01:00  | 2014-12-31 23:15:00.0000000   | 2014-12-31 23:15:00.0000000 +00:00
```

Comment: Question: What is the 3rd parameter ('1') in the function: 
"convert(datetime2,@dt,1) as Converted" ?  If I set this parameter to 0, it does not convert correctly (ignores time zone) for me. Values of 1 and 2 seem to work fine.

Comment: @Marty131 It specifies whether to ignore the `+01:00` timezone part or not in the conversion.  On my machine only `0` for ignore and `1` for don't ignore work.